# How do I create a code that lets me use an array of 10 thermistors on one arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, code-optimization, thermistor

I am new to programming and am trying to create an array of 10 thermistors on one arduino. So far I have found a code for Temperature Sensor Using NTC Thermistor that is only for one thermistor. How do I fix this code for 10 thermistors?
Here is the link where I found the code.
https://thecustomizewindows.com/2020/10/temperature-sensor-using-ntc-thermistor-arduino-ntc/
The code below has been changed a little for the thermistor I am using.
Thank you.

```
#define RT0 10000   // Ω
#define B 3470      // K
#define VCC 5       //Supply voltage
#define R 10000     // R=10kΩ


float RT, VR, ln, TX, T0, VRT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  T0 = 25 + 273.15;                 //Temperature, Celsius to Kelvin
}

void loop() {
  VRT = analogRead(A0);              //Acquisition analog value of VRT
  VRT = (5.00 / 1023.00) * VRT;      //Conversion to voltage
  VR = VCC - VRT;
  RT = VRT / (VR / R);               //Resistance of RT

  ln = log(RT / RT0);
  TX = (1 / ((ln / B) + (1 / T0))); //Temperature from NTC thermistor

  TX = TX - 273.15;                 //Conversion to Celsius

  Serial.print("Temperature:");
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(TX);
  Serial.print("C\t\t");
  Serial.print((TX * 1.8) + 32);    //Conversion to Fahrenheit
  Serial.println("F");
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: the answer depends on how you intend to connect 10 thermistors to an arduino

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said which (of the many kinds) of "Arduino" you plan to use, but Uno being the most common, I'll assume that. You also haven't said why/whether you must use a particular temperature sensor, but if you can be flexible about that, there will more choices of solution.

First, thermistors: You read a thermistors with an an A/D converter. Uno has an A/D converter but it has only 6 channels available - not enough for your spec of 10 sensors.

- You could add an external A/D multiplexer with 5 channels fed into one of your on-board channels plus the remaining 5 on-board channels.
- Or add a 10-channel multiplexer for all 10 sensors and feed it to one of the on-board A/D channels. This is better because it's simpler - all of the sensor signals will be processed identically, and all accessed the same way in the code.
- Add an external 10-channel A/D. It will cost a little more but will be even easier to work with.

If you don't require thermistors, I'd suggest the Dallas/Maxim DS18b20 "1-wire" sensors. The "1-Wire" bus is a proprietary protocol developed by Dallas Semiconductor on which these sensors depend. You use one, simple, twisted-pair bus to access all of them, needing only 1 Arduino pin (and ground) to provide both power and communication to/from the sensors. Libraries are available to manage the bus and the communication. The 1-wire bus can be in a linear or a branched configuration, to suit your installation. You can use 2 wires (ground and power+data) or 3 wires (ground, power, data). Here's a link to the [DS18b20 data sheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) for the details.

Update:
I didn't really answer your question about *coding* for 10 thermistors (since you can't directly connect 10 thermistors to an Uno), I'll try to address that now without getting into any more detail about what kind of sensors you use or how you connect them.

You'll need to read 10 sensors, compute the sensor data to temperature and store it, and do whatever you plan to do with the temperature value. Your present code prints it (as both degC and degF, but let's just describe that part as printing the value).

You'll need a `for( )` loop that executes 10 times, once for each sensor, where the loop index tells which sensor (0-9) you'll be processing. In time the loop executes, read a sensor, compute the temperature from what the sensor gives you, if it isn't already in the units you need, and print the value. So structuring that as if it were code (but I won't be writing it out in full C++) it would look like:

```
tell all 10 sensors to take a measurement; // if necessary
for( i = 0; i < 10; ++i ){
   read data from sensor[i];
   convert it to temperature;      // depends on the sensor
   print the temperature value;
}
```

If that is all you want to do, code this loop in your `setup()` function. Each time you reset the Arduino, it will measure and print all 10 temperatures and stop (actually, loop forever, doing nothing, until you power it down). If you want it to do this periodically, code this loop in your `loop()` function, with a `delay(5000);` statement after it. Now it will print the 10 temperatures every 5 seconds. You can change the 5000 (it's in milliseconds) to whatever period you want.

But it's the details that get you. You've got code to read and convert thermistors but your Arduino can't directly connect to 10 thermistors. If you use an external multiplexer, then you'll have to include code for that. If you use DS18b20 1-Wire sensors, you'll need to download and use the code library for those, as well as converting their 1/16-degC units to the units of your choice.

I'd recommend you start with 2 or 3 thermistors since you have the code for them, and write the loop for those. Once that's working, you'll have the answer to your title question. Then you'll have to decide how to connect 10 sensors of some kind, as I wrote about earlier. That will involve some additional coding, for an analog multiplexer, or for 1-Wire sensors, or whatever solution you choose. Just expand your experiment by small steps at a time and get each step working before you move on.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/issue-with-cd74hc4067-mux-on-high-values has code for a 16-channel multiplexer attached to A0